# Why angularJs ur changing into Base64Format

Tags: angularjs

Here i'm trying to uplode some data into sqlser From mvc-to-webApi why my url not binding that pat And also its comverting into Base64Format

```
http://localhost:30952/api/EmpSave/?0=%7B&1=%22&10=%22&11=a&12=a&13=%22&14=,&15=%22&16=G&17=e&18=n&19=_&2=E&20=I&21=d&22=%22&23=:&24=%22&25=1&26=%22&27=,&28=%22&29=C&3=_&30=o&31=u&32=n&33=t&34=r&35=y&36=I&37=d&38=%22&39=:&4=N&40=1&41=,&42=%22&43=S&44=t&45=a&46=t&47=e&48=I&49=d&5=a&50=%22&51=:&52=1&53=,&54=%22&55=C&56=i&57=t&58=y&59=I&6=m&60=d&61=%22&62=:&63=2&64=%7D&7=e&8=%22&9=:
```

**cntrl.Js**

```
 $scope.SaveDb = function (emp) {
        if ($scope.SubmitText == "Save") {
            var saving = MyService.SaveEmp(emp);
        }
    }
```

**service.Js**

```
 var ApiUrl = "http://localhost:30952/"
     this.SaveEmp = function (emp) {
            var saves = $http({
                url: ApiUrl+"api/EmpSave/",
                method: "POST",
                params: JSON.stringify(emp),
                dataType:JSON,
                content: { 'content-Type': 'application/Json' }

            })
            return saves;
        }
```

Comment: i think your url contains some space in between

Comment: wer i need space in url?Evne No Use

Comment: if you are need space in between the url, then url will encoded and converted into base64. browser will not take any space, it will replace the space by %20 and for `"` it will replace into %22. for more information please check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: its good but why data is not targetting Urls

Comment: r u getting any error ?

Comment: i think there will be error in server side, may be server side retrun OK 200 instead of 500 for error message also

Comment: sure, give me your id and password

Comment: wait for some time.

Comment: not connecting with your computer

Comment: now its ok sir its working r not

Comment: yes it is working

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not base64 encoding. This is URL encoding.

It happens because you're transforming your object to a JSON string, and then passing the result as the $http params. params go into the query string of the URL, and they're encoded to make the URL valid.

You probably want to send the JSON as the body of your request. The correct way to do that is

```
$http({
    url: ApiUrl+"api/EmpSave/",
    method: "POST",
    data: emp
});
```

or simply

```
$http.post(ApiUrl+"api/EmpSave/", emp);
```

All of this, and more, is of course detailed in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: it says Unsupported Meadia Type

Comment: That's a backend problem. Your server doesn't seem to accept JSON.

Comment: then how can i red req for json? but wen i try to fetching data from s/r its fine

Comment: Please use proper English words, punctuation and capitalization. I can't read your sentence.

Comment: sry? Here i'm fetching data From WebApi s/r its working fine But When i try 2 POST data its not Binding that Url

Comment: Please use proper English words, punctuation and capitalization. `sry`is not a word. `i'm` should be written `I'm`. `s/r` is not a word. `fine But When i try 2 POST` should be written `fine. But when I try to post`. Making it a hassle to even read and understand your questions doesn't encourage me, at all, to help you.